# having issues passing a function in pd.apply() and np.vectorize() but not using simpler methods?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Preface: i'm a newbie at using pandas and python. i've always used SPSS for data manipulation and coding and have began switching over for versatility and speed.

So the data i'm currently working on is in SPSS format, which I read into pandas using pd.read_spss. the date format used in spss (adate) is mm/dd/yyyy, but when reading into pandas becomes a scientific notation e.g. (01/01/1900 as 1.34596e+10).

I defined a function to correct those dates into their intended format:

```
def adate(date):
    date = pd.to_datetime((df[date]/86400)-141428, unit='D').dt.date
    return date
```

and this works to reformat a column in pandas by calling

```
df['FilingDt'] = adate('FilingDt')
```

and i want to come up with an approach to change multiple date columns in one go. the issue is when using df['date_filed'] = df['date_filed'].apply(adate) i get this error:

```
df['FilingDt'] = df['FilingDt'].apply(adate)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/nathaniellemahieu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 13593916800.0


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-109267f6c366>", line 1, in <module>
    df['FilingDt'] = df['FilingDt'].apply(adate)

  File "/Users/nathaniellemahieu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "<ipython-input-1-83b46e00b8fb>", line 24, in adate
    date = pd.to_datetime((df[date]/86400)-141428, unit='D').dt.date

  File "/Users/nathaniellemahieu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/Users/nathaniellemahieu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 13593916800
```

and trying to use df["FilingDt"] = np.vectorize(adate) gets me values of:

```
<numpy.vectorize object at 0x147165a10>
```

how can i fix this or set up this function so that i can apply it on multiple columns in one go?

Comment: Don't try to use `np.vectorize`

Comment: Can't you just loop on the desired column names?

Comment: I don't have the data so I just tried to guess. Is this correct: `df['FilingDt'] = df['FilingDt'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime((x/86400)-141428, unit='D').dt.date)`